# MySQL: Encoding problem on CREATE TABLE statement

Tags: mysql, database, encoding, smartcontracts, emoji

I want to create a new MySQL table with specific column names. I configured charset but I guess it's only working for content, not for column names.

What I try to:

```
CREATE TABLE  (
 INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
✉ VARCHAR(255),
 VARCHAR(255),
_id INT(6),
 TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 DATE,
 TINYINT(1),
 TINYINT(1),
 TINYINT(1)
)
```

This caused an error, so I also tried:

```
CREATE TABLE Person (
 INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
✉ VARCHAR(255),
 VARCHAR(255),
_id INT(6),
 TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 DATE,
 TINYINT(1),
 TINYINT(1),
 TINYINT(1)
)
```

Even an error. Feels like MySQL is hard stuff. What can I do that my database will accept my statements?

Comment: This looks like a terrible design choice...

Comment: [Schema Object Names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html): "Permitted characters in quoted identifiers include the full Unicode Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP), except U+0000: ASCII: U+0001 .. U+007F, Extended: U+0080 .. U+FFFF". 4-byte unicode characters are not permitted.

Comment: Even in SQL Server (which you also initially tagged), unless you define the database as using a binary collation you'll get a similar error, due the collation seeing some emoticon characters as "equal": [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4ce53a806ada0ac7e20a5e2bbd46f802) [Binary Collated Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Y8H8.png) But, I repeat my point. This is a terrible design choice; just *don't* do this.

Comment: Emojis are cute pictures for text messages. Why are you trying to use them in serious programming?

Comment: @Barmar Emojis are cute. You're totally right ! But that's not the point of using it. They are the only characters that can be modified by a suffix. I.e. see [skin tones](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_emoji_skin_tones.asp). Using them gives you an huge advantage. If you change value of a variable in programming, there is no way to rollback the variable to the old value without using a new one. By extending an emoji with i.e. a skin tone, you can by changing encoding two times. If you had a deep dive to smart contracts, this method reduce your GAS fee. So it's all about the money. 

Comment: I didn't quite follow that, but it sounds like you want to change the column identifier with skin tones as a means of flagging data changes without changing data? How does that work? Changing a column's name requires DDL, which will apply the change to all rows in the table and all sessions using the table. It will also cause an implicit commit, and all the other implications of DDL. I think this is not a practical solution even without considering the idea of using emojis. This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, MySQL and MariaDB limit database/table/column names to BMP.  That is, "utf8" (aka "utf8mb3"), not "utf8mb4".